# Reading a YAML file in golang while the YAML file contains unicode characters (like "a\u0000b")

Tags: string, go, unicode, yaml

I have an issue with reading a YAML file, and the YAML file contains Unicode character escaping. But when I load the YAML file, and print the `fileInfo`, the string which contains Unicode character escaping (e.g. `'a\u0000b'`) was escaped when using `unMarshal()` function.

**Here is my YAML file (`conf.yml`):**

```
topicList:
  - source: 'test'
    target: 'temp'
  - source: 'a\u0000b'
    target: 'temp'
```

**And my code is:**

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "strings"

    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

type Config struct {
    TopicList []Topic `yaml:"topicList"`
}

type Topic struct {
    Source string `yaml:"source" json:"source"`
    Target string `yaml:"target" json:"target"`
}

func main() {
    cfg, err := NewConfig("conf.yml")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("load config fail: ", err)
    }
    for _, s := range cfg.TopicList {
        fmt.Println("\n +++++ sourceTopic = ", s.Source)
        if strings.Contains(s.Source, "\u0000") {
            fmt.Println("\n topic contains unicode character. topic = ", s.Source)
        }
    }
}

func NewConfig(file string) (conf *Config, err error) {
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(file)
    if err != nil {
       return 
    }
    conf = &Config{}
    err = yaml.Unmarshal(data, conf)
    return 
}
```

**And the result is:**

```
+++++ sourceTopic =  test

+++++ sourceTopic =  a\u0000b
```

**But the result I expected is:**

```
+++++ sourceTopic =  test

+++++ sourceTopic =  ab

topic contains unicode character. topic =  ab
```

Why cannot I get the expected answer? How to fix the code? Thank you!

Comment: A note on terminology: All characters are unicode characters. Your issue is with escaping, not unicode.

Comment: why the string which contains "\u0000" is escaped when using unMarshal() function? If I fmt.Println("a\u0000b"), return "ab".

Comment: Because `fmt.Println` interprets the escape sequence, but the yaml unmarshaler does not.

Comment: OK, how to fix the code? I cannot find the solve function in yaml  unmarshal(). thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code is fine (needs no fixing), the problem is that you used single quotes in your input YAML. Escape sequences in single quotes are interpreted as-is (that is: *not* interpreted), so `'a\u0000b'` will denote the exact string `"a\u0000b"`, or in Go interpreted string literal syntax: `"a\\u0000b"`.

Instead the source YAML must use double quotes: `"a\u000b"` for the escape to be interpreted / decoded.

Quoting from [YAML spec: Escape Sequences:](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2776092)

> **Note that escape sequences are only interpreted in [double-quoted scalars](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#style/flow/double-quoted).** In all other [scalar styles](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#style/scalar/), the “\” character has no special meaning and non-[printable](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#printable%20character//) characters are not available.

If you change your input YAML to this:

```
topicList:
  - source: 'test'
    target: 'temp'
  - source: "a\u0000b"
    target: 'temp'
```

Then the output of your app will be:

```
 +++++ sourceTopic =  test

 +++++ sourceTopic =  ab

 topic contains unicode character. topic =  ab
```